# How to start textmate in command line

Tags: textmate

Because I didn't create textmate link when installing, so it can not find 'mate' command. who can help me to deal with this? thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Even though is question is more suited for Super User, I'll bite:

> Creating a symbolic link can either be done by selecting Help → Terminal Usage… from the menu, or from the shell by running something like the following:

```
ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate ~/bin/mate
```

> This assumes that you have ~/bin created and in your path and that TextMate is installed in /Applications.

Therefore, I'd recommend looking inside of the `Textmate.app` bundle :)

([Source](http://manual.macromates.com/en/using_textmate_from_terminal.html))

Comment: Mavericks was acting strange with a bunch of the other solutions, but Help → Terminal Usage couldn't have been simpler. Cheers!

Answer (score 81):

Textmate 2:

From the menu:

Textmate -> Preferences -> Terminal: click `install`

For more information read the "Terminal Preferences" from Help

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Then to write commands, preface them in command line with `mate`.

Answer (score 9):

Install TextMate

If you're using bash, open .bashrc or .bash_profile; or if you're using zsh the open .zshrc and add

```
 export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/mate -w"
```

Navigate to the Preferences -> Terminal and click install

[image: TextMate latest version Preferences Image]

Answer (score 5):

TextMate will create the symbolic link you need.  Launch TextMate as you would any other Cocoa app, and under the "Help" menu, select "Terminal Usage..."  A simple GUI presents you with some defaults you will almost certainly use but can tweek if necessary.  Click "Create Link" and you're set.

Answer (score 2):

Create a symboling link to bin folder

```
ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate ~/bin/mate
```

then export all links to path variable

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

for more detailed information go to [TextMate's official help page](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/textmate-shell-utility-tmmate/).

Answer (score 0):

Open file with TextMate from terminal:

```
open -a TextMate path_to_file
```